# Correct way to Deserialize paypal response in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, json, paypal, json.net

**Introduction**

I am working with paypal payment implementation for my demo project.When user confirm request, the response and request received in json format(as most of you guys knew).

**Code Setup**

Action Where data is being 'parsed'

```
string str = JObject.Parse(executedPayment.ConvertToJson()).ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
var payerInfo = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<ResponseMappingObject.Payer_Info>(str);

foreach(var item in payerInfo)
{
string abc = payerInfo.first_name;
string abc2 = payerInfo.last_name;
}
```

Mapping Class which i added for comfort

```
public class Payer_Info
        {
            public string email { get; set; }
            public string first_name { get; set; }
            public string last_name { get; set; }
            public string payer_id { get; set; }
        }
```

**Problem**

Normally, in "string str" data received and parsed successfully and deserialized also.But the error while building

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
>   'ResponseMappingObject.Payer_Info' because
>   ResponseMappingObject.Payer_Info' does not contain a public definition
>   for 'GetEnumerator'

**Question**

How to solve this problem if its proper way of deserializing json response?

Can we deserialization in javascript if its safe?

**Edit : Json Response**

```
{  
   "id":"PAY-9C822419X38654121KZ4O27I",
   "create_time":"2015-12-22T06:28:32Z",
   "intent":"authorize",
   "payer":{  
      "payment_method":"paypal",
      "payer_info":{  
         "email":"suhail339-buyer@gmail.com",
         "first_name":"test",
         "last_name":"buyer",
         "payer_id":"S75P265T8HXXY",
         "phone":"4086197056",
         "shipping_address":{  
            "recipient_name":"test buyer",
            "line1":"1 Main St",
            "city":"San Jose",
            "country_code":"US",
            "postal_code":"95131",
            "state":"CA"
         }
      }
   },
   "cart":"0HD75068VV063304H",
   "transactions":[  
      {  
         "related_resources":[  
            {  
               "authorization":{  
                  "id":"7BM47750VM8619157",
                  "create_time":"2015-12-22T06:28:32Z",
                  "update_time":"2015-12-22T06:28:32Z",
                  "amount":{  
                     "currency":"USD",
                     "total":"249.99",
                     "details":{  
                        "shipping":"0.00",
                        "subtotal":"249.99",
                        "tax":"0.00"
                     }
                  },
                  "payment_mode":"INSTANT_TRANSFER",
                  "state":"authorized",
                  "protection_eligibility":"ELIGIBLE",
                  "protection_eligibility_type":"ITEM_NOT_RECEIVED_ELIGIBLE,UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT_ELIGIBLE",
                  "parent_payment":"PAY-9C822419X38654121KZ4O27I",
                  "valid_until":"2016-01-20T06:28:32Z",
                  "links":[  
                     {  
                        "href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/authorization/7BM47750VM8619157",
                        "rel":"self",
                        "method":"GET"
                     },
                     {  
                        "href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/authorization/7BM47750VM8619157/capture",
                        "rel":"capture",
                        "method":"POST"
                     },
                     {  
                        "href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/authorization/7BM47750VM8619157/void",
                        "rel":"void",
                        "method":"POST"
                     },
                     {  
                        "href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/authorization/7BM47750VM8619157/reauthorize",
                        "rel":"reauthorize",
                        "method":"POST"
                     },
                     {  
                        "href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-9C822419X38654121KZ4O27I",
                        "rel":"parent_payment",
                        "method":"GET"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ],
         "amount":{  
            "currency":"USD",
            "total":"249.99",
            "details":{  
               "shipping":"0.00",
               "subtotal":"249.99",
               "tax":"0.00"
            }
         },
         "description":"100 Pairs with all services",
         "item_list":{  
            "shipping_address":{  
               "line1":"1 Main St",
               "city":"San Jose",
               "country_code":"US",
               "postal_code":"95131",
               "state":"CA"
            }
         }
      }
   ],
   "state":"approved",
   "links":[  
      {  
         "href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-9C822419X38654121KZ4O27I",
         "rel":"self",
         "method":"GET"
      }
   ]
}
```

If someone has idea about that problem, please do help.Any kind of help or reference will be appreciated.Thanks for your time.

Comment: You receive JSON, then you deserialize it using `JObject`, and serialize it again using `ToString()`. And then you deserialize it again using `JavaScriptSerializer`. Oh...Actually, we need your JSON example to show what format you should use. And you definitely cannot iterate through the single object using `foreach`.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev thanks for reply, i will update question with response json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API gets you a [c# object](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#payment-object) ([code source](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/blob/develop/Source/SDK/Api/Payment.cs)), use its properties, there is nothing to deserialize. You don't need to convert to JSON, JSON.parse, serialize, deserialize again. For example:

```
var firstName = executedPayment.payer.payer_info.first_name;
var lastName = executedPayment.payer.payer_info.last_name;
```

Intellisense will be a great help to "discover" all properties you need.

Comment: thanks for the help, that is correct and safest method.+1 for help